# Having trouble scraping the opengraph

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a web page with NodeJS. I'm getting my data with the `request` module and parsing with `cheerio`. However I've noticed something: when I visit some pages with chrome (say, [this nyt article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/11/us/politics/paul-ryan-a-mirage-candidate-wages-a-parallel-campaign.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=0)), and inspect the source, there is exactly one match for the tag `meta` with an attribute `property` of `og:title`. If I request the same page from my Node scraper and inspect the tags, I have 108 `meta` tags with an attribute `property` set to `og:title`. *I have tried playing around with User-Agents, to no avent.*

- What is the cause of the discrepancy?
- Is this done intentionally on these websites to discourage scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problems were the product of my scraping paranoia (where I believe every site is out to lock their information behind layer of scraping defenses) and my lack of knowledge of `cheerio` combined. To anyone having similar problems:

`$(tag).attr(attribute,value)` will set every `tag`'s `attribute` to value.

To find all the `tag`s with `attribute` set to `value`, this is what you want:

```
$(tag[attribute = 'value']);
```